# android SHA-256 certificate from debug apk file

Tags: android, apk, sha256, android-deep-link, debug-build

I am working on declaring app site association in assetLinks.json file and as a part I need to declare the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint.  have a debug apk and is there any way to get its SHA-256 certificate fingerprint?

Answer (score 2):

Displaying the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint of any signed APK is pretty simple: You just need `apksigner` from Android SDK which is included in the `build-tools` Android SDK package (there is one for each Android version e.g. "31.0.0").

As `apksigner.bat` respectively `apksigner.sh` is not in the PATH you need to execute it with it's full path (which is omitted in the following example).

Example from an debug app:

```
apksigner verify --print-certs Application-debug.apk

Signer #1 certificate DN: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: ce512066e25ef809f964c8c382a292bbf17d163079edc7cf2f90a89adad4bb66
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 06ea5851f235339da7c75775b697f12e9139dc2d
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 61663acdd59671e62dc2a2c4ee2bf20a
```